# JScript regexp: start of line doesn't work?

Tags: regex, windows, jscript

I want to cut path from config file:

```
var out = '#Path to the database root';
out += '\ndatadir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/Data/"';
out += '\nblah-blah-blah-blah-blah';

var re = new RegExp('^datadir="(.*)"', 'g');
var result = out.match(re);
if (result == null){    
    WScript.Echo("datadir not found");
}
WScript.Echo("datadir=" + RegExp.lastParen);
```

but my code doesn't found the required string. On the other hand, if i remove the 'caret' symbol (`^`) it works. It's not a solution because I want to make sure I grab data from line which really starts with that word.

**Update:**
In fact '\n' is really the new line for me despite single quote. For example

```
WScript.Echo("out=" + out);
```

produces

```
out=#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/Data/"
blah-blah-blah-blah-blah
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A `^` boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) normally anchors to the beginning of the entire input string rather than the beginning of each individual line.

The [`m` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) can be used to anchor at each line instead:

```
var re = new RegExp('^datadir="(.*)"', 'gm');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PjLd4/

Comment: +1, I read too fast and thought his `\n` was burned into a string. Pulled my answer.